# HTML body tags within Powershell

Tags: html, powershell

I am new to Powershell and HTML. I am using Powershell code within an HTML file to display AD passwords expiry criteria and finally send it as an email. The email getting generated is having the header and footer displayed properly but the middle portion of the code which queries the AD is not showing any rows in the HTML table.
I am suspecting there is something wrong in my use of $body +=     but this is how some of the documentation has suggested. Also when I individually run the Powershell commandlets I can see that records are being returned.
Can someone please suggest where I could be going wrong?

```
 #Remove Digital Signature Check
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

 import-module activedirectory
# $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

$MailParams = @{
To = @("iq@mail.com")
From = "iq@mail.com"
Subject = "HTML Table"
SmtpServer = "mail.server.com"
}
  
 try {
   
            
        $body = 
        "<div>
            <p>
                <b><span >Attention IT Group:</span></b>
            </p>
            <BR>
          </DIV>

          <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width=94%>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=2 style='width:100.0%; border:solid #1F4E79 1.0pt; background:#1F4E79; padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'
                        <p >
                            <SPAN style='font-size:22.0pt; font-weight:bold; font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,sans-serif; color:white'>
                                Password Expirations for Service Accounts 
                            </SPAN>
                        </P>
                    </td>
                </tr>"
# **** Need Code for Expire within < 1 Day ******
        $body +=    Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $True}  -SearchBase "OU=Service Accounts,OU=SG1,OU=TAW,DC=wt,DC=ad,DC=cit,DC=com" `
                 -Properties * | 
                 Sort-Object -Descending -Property  @{Expression={($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365) - [DateTime]::Now).Days}}|
                # sort-object -Descending -property SamAccountName |  
                 Where-Object{($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365) - [DateTime]::Now).Days -le  1 }|
    Select-Object -property `
           @{Name="LogonName";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}} ,
            @{Name="PasswordExpiration";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")}}  |
    convertto-HTML -Fragment 

# **** Need Code for Expire within 7 Days ( 2 - 7 Days) ******
        $body +=   Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $True}  -SearchBase "OU=Service Accounts,OU=SG1,OU=TAW,DC=wt,DC=ad,DC=cit,DC=com" `
                 -Properties * | 
                 Sort-Object -Descending -Property  @{Expression={($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365) - [DateTime]::Now).Days}}|
                # sort-object -Descending -property SamAccountName |  
                 Where-Object{($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365) - [DateTime]::Now).Days -in (2,7) }|
    Select-Object -property `
           @{Name="LogonName";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}} ,
            @{Name="PasswordExpiration";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")}}  |
    convertto-HTML -Fragment 

# **** Need Code for Expire within 7 Days ( 8 - 15 Days) ******
        $body +=   Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $True}  -SearchBase "OU=Service Accounts,OU=SG1,OU=TAW,DC=wt,DC=ad,DC=cit,DC=com" `
                 -Properties * | 
                 Sort-Object -Descending -Property  @{Expression={($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365) - [DateTime]::Now).Days}}|
                # sort-object -Descending -property SamAccountName |  
                 Where-Object{($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365) - [DateTime]::Now).Days -in (8,15) }|
    Select-Object -property `
           @{Name="LogonName";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}} ,
            @{Name="PasswordExpiration";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")}}  |
    convertto-HTML -Fragment 


# **** Need Code for Expire within 7 Days (16- 30  Days) ******
        $body +=  Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $True}  -SearchBase "OU=Service Accounts,OU=SG1,OU=TAW,DC=wt,DC=ad,DC=cit,DC=com" `
                 -Properties * | 
                 Sort-Object -Descending -Property  @{Expression={($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365) - [DateTime]::Now).Days}}|
                # sort-object -Descending -property SamAccountName |  
                 Where-Object{($_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365) - [DateTime]::Now).Days -in (16,30) }|
    Select-Object -property `
           @{Name="LogonName";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}} ,
            @{Name="PasswordExpiration";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")}}  |
    convertto-HTML -Fragment  

#*****   Footer of Email****
    $body += "   </tbody>
               </table>
                <BR>
                <p style='margin-bottom:2.0pt'>
                    <span style='font-family:&quot;Calibri&quot;,sans-serif; color:black'> Management team<br> </span><span style='color:black'>
                    </span>
                </p>
                <BR>
             " 
    $MailParams.body = $body
                                         
}


catch { 
write-output "No records found for one of the criteria" 
} 
 
Send-MailMessage @MailParams -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: `ConvertTo-Html -Fragment` will still output a self-contained `<table>` element, so you're nesting new `<table>`'s inside the one you already have. Does the records appear if you inspect the raw html of the email that you receive?

Comment: This calls Get-ADUser 3x.  Suggest dividing this differently.  Pull the data once into a collection.  Filter into three smaller collections.  Use those collections to generate emails.  Also, make it work as plain text, exported to a CSV. This will allow you to troubleshoot your filtering and such.  Then make it export a plain text email to a text file, which will allow troubleshooting the generation of the email.  Then converting it to html output, so you can troubleshoot the html generation.  In other words, first get your data pull working 100%.  Then increase complexity in a  phased manner.

Comment: Xalorous, thats exactly how we approached this but the user requirements have changed so we had to add some complexity to the code.     Mathias ,  the records appear if I inspect the raw output of the html, so why is it that it does not display in the email ?   Thank you both for your valuable suggestions hopefully I am able to resolve this with help from this forum.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be the full answer, and I'm basically repeating what people have already said. Especially the comment to not call `Get-ADUser` three times.

- Your `Get-Aduser` should be *filtered* with a query - don't return *every* enabled account and then use a `Where` clause. I assume you want accounts with password last set date up to 30 days before what will be the 1 year anniversary of the password date? Grab all of those and then use your `Where` clause on the results.
- Separate the code where you're generating your AD report from the code where you generate the HTML. And separate that from the code where you construct the mail message. You currently have three different processes jumbled together, and this makes troubleshooting more complex.
- Output your fragments as HTML files and test individually. Outlook is really picky about the HTML it renders and `<div>` and `<span>` can be a drama. Of course they work in Outlook, but sometimes some combination doesn't work. I keep it as simple as possible.

Here's an example of how the AD filter and subsequent slicing could work.

```bsh
$1year = (get-date).AddDays(-365)
$30days = (get-date).AddDays(-334)
$tomorrow = (get-date).AddDays(-364)
$15days = (get-date).AddDays(-350)

# Get all the users that will be included in the report - one AD query
$users = get-aduser -filter 'passwordlastset -gt $1year -and passwordlastset -lt $30days -and enabled -eq "True"' `
    -properties passwordlastset -searchbase "OU=myOU,DC=example,DC=com"

# break down the user list into the report categories
$expTomorrow = $users | where {$_.passwordLastSet -le $tomorrow} | 
    sort -Property passwordlastset -Descending |select -property `
        @{Name="LogonName";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}}, 
        @{Name="PasswordExpiration";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")}}
$exp15Days = $users | where {$_.passwordLastSet -gt $tomorrow -and $_.passwordLastSet -le $15days} | 
    sort -Property passwordlastset -Descending | select -property `
        @{Name="LogonName";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}}, 
        @{Name="PasswordExpiration";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")}}
$expOver15Days = $users | where {$_.passwordLastSet -gt $15days} | 
    sort -Property passwordlastset -Descending | select -property `
         @{Name="LogonName";Expression={$_.SamAccountName}}, 
         @{Name="PasswordExpiration";Expression={$_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays(365).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")}}

# assemble body
$preHTML = @'
...
'@
$postHTML = @'
...
'@

$body = $preHTML
$body += [fragment1]
$body += ...

# Send message
Send-MailMessage ...
```

With the three collections of users for your report, you can check the output of each of those individually to see if they look correct.

For your testing, do the `Convertto-HTML -fragment` on some collection examples, wrap them inside a really basic HTML header, output to file, and see how they look in the browser.

Once that looks good, create a codeblock to assemble the entire body into the `$body` variable. Remember that some of those user collections might be empty, so you'll need to append to `$body` so it doesn't error on an empty collection (obviously test that).

I agree with the comment not to wrap the body in yet another table. Just do a simple paragraph with a text style for your heading. Leave out the `<span>` tags unless you're actually styling the text. Once again, check how it renders in the browser when output as a simple HTML file.

Then your `Send-MailMessage` can be in its own codeblock. It makes it a lot easier to see where something's going wrong.